# Express 403 External Post

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, post, cors

I am trying to receive an HTTP POST request from an external provider on my Express server.

When I launch Postman, I get response correctly. But when I do it from a service, no. So I understand that the problem must be from CORS (which is what Postman doesn't use) but I have everything configured correctly:

index.js

```
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
app.use(cors);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type, Accept,Authorization,Origin");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
  });

app.post('/example', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    status: 'OK'
  });
});
```

It works with postman.

Also, to rule out, I have configured CORS on my NGINX server:

```
[...]
Last-Modified: Tue, 28 Dec 2021 23:03:05 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "61cb97a9-9ef"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Does anyone know where I can have the error and how could it be fixed?

Comment: Do you get a CORS error in your browser's Console tab? If so, what does the message say? For one thing, you claim to have configured CORS correctly but you should know that `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` is incompatible with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: No, because not is a front load. Is a service calling Express backend.

Comment: I don't understand your comment...

Comment: browser console tab does not show nothing because i am not on the browser. it is a service doing a POST req

Comment: CORS only applies to browsers, not to other user agents. So what you're facing is unrelated to CORS. Please provide more details about how you send the request to that Express backend and explain what happens. Do you get a response at all? Does it just hang? etc.

Answer (score -1):

Okay as regards your error which seems to be pointing to a cors issue, Make sure cors is configured this way on your server:

const cors = require("cors");

var corsOptions = {
origin: "*",
methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
preflightContinue: false,
optionsSuccessStatus: 204
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

Comment: It has not worked. I know that the server receives something and cuts it, because it has a peak of activity, but it rejects the connection before capturing any information

Comment: is there any error showing on your server console? if there is any, You can send a screenshot of it

Comment: No, the Nginx console only has 3 errors from a bad configuration that I did with the tests.
The Node console does not capture anything either.
However, I watch live when I launch the service and see a spike in server CPU usage (barely 3-5%) so something is coming through.

Comment: @AlfredoHinarejos About those errors in the NGINX console, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70526302/express-403-external-post#comment124675070_70526302